# Parsing XML file with no closing tag with Python

Tags: python, xml

I am not very familiar with Python and I would need you help regarding this sample of the XML file I need to export in a CSV file:

```
<FORMAT_TITRE_3>2-2 - Texte en application duquel la convention est conclue :</FORMAT_TITRE_3> La procédure de délégation [...]territoriales.
<FORMAT_TITRE_3>2-3 - Objet de la délégation :</FORMAT_TITRE_3>
<TR /> Convention de délégation [...]Fussy.
<TR /> Domaine de la délégation : assainissement collectif
<TR /> Durée de la délégation : xx ans.
<TR /> Lieu principal d'exécution de la délégation : Territoire communal de Fussy.
<TR /> Code Nuts : FR241
<FORMAT_TITRE_3>2-4 - Information sur le montant [...] origine) :</FORMAT_TITRE_3> The contract amounts to : xxx E HT.
<FORMAT_TITRE_3>2-5 - Classification CPV :</FORMAT_TITRE_3> 90110000-1.
<FORMAT_TITRE_3>3 - Procédure :</FORMAT_TITRE_3>
```

When using an ElementTree method I am able to extract the text displayed after a closing tag (e.g. "La procédure de délégation [...]territoriales." on line 1) and also the text after the `<TR />` tag. 
The rest of the file has a classic structure so my codes work well but I now stuck with those weird tags. Below, a sample of my codes:

```
        # takes as input an xml root, a dictionary where to store the parsed values and an id number suggesting uniqueness of the current node
        def parse_node(root, dict, id):
            # Parse this node
            tag_dict = OrderedDict()
            for key, value in root.attrib.items():
                if id > 1: # if there are more than one childs with the same tag
                    tag_dict[root.tag + str(id) + ':' + key] = value
                else:
                    tag_dict[root.tag + ':' + key] = value
            # Get children of node
            children = root.getchildren()
            # If node has one or more child
            if len(children) >= 1:
                # Loop through all the children
                tag_dict_id = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
                for child in children:
                    tag_dict_id[child.tag] += 1 # keep track of the children
                    # call to recursion function
                    # Parse children
                    parse_node(child, tag_dict, tag_dict_id[child.tag])
            # If does not have children and is the 'search_node'
            elif len(children) == 0:
                # Store the text inside the node.
                if id > 1:
                    tag_dict[root.tag + str(id) + ':text'] = root.text
                else:
                    tag_dict[root.tag + ':text'] = root.text
            # update the current dictionary with the new data
            dict.update(tag_dict)
            return dict
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: What weird tags? What is the question?

Comment: Could you give an example of what the CSV file should look like? And do you want to keep the 'La procédure de délégation [...]territoriales.' text or not?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. @Daniel, the weird tag refer to the  <TR /> ones , with the backslash at the right and not the left. My question is the following (my apologies if I was not clear): how can I parse all information in such a XML file?

Comment: @nander-speerstra, the CSV file should include the text between the tags <FORMAT_TITRE_3> as the variable name (line 1) and the text on the right on the second line. However, for the text displayed after the  <TR /> tag, I think one should loop over "2-3 - Objet de la délégation :" for each <TR /> such as:  "2-3 - Objet de la délégation :1" ==>"Convention de délégation [...]Fussy." and  "2-3 - Objet de la délégation :2"==>Domaine de la délégation : assainissement collectif, and so on...